# Visio import SVG custom shape data

Tags: svg, visio

I am able to import an svg file into visio. I would like to attach custom data to the elements in the SVG file so that when imported the data will show up in the shape data of the element in the visio drawing. I know that I can assign this data to the drawing after the fact, but I would like it to be imported with the file.

ADDITIONAL: If I add shape data then export to svg the data takes the appearance of

```
        <v:custProps>
            <v:cp v:nameU="this_is_data_name" v:lbl="this_is_data_label" v:type="0" v:langID="1033"
                    v:val="VT4(this is data value)"/>
        </v:custProps>
```

These custProps is the data I want IMPORTED with the SVG. Can I import this data/how?

Comment: What is stopping you from adding the data the same way to the SVG (i.e. adding <v:customProps> elements to svg?

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to add the namespace declaration `xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:visio"` as well.

Comment: @Nikolay I tried that. Strangely, visio doesn't recognize those elements when importing.

Comment: Have you added the namespace @ccprog mentioned? "v:" refers to a xml namespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ccprog comment sent me in the correct direction, but there was more that I needed to add. The correct namespace needed was

```
xmlns:v="http://schemas.microsoft.com/visio/2003/SVGExtensions/"
```

Additionally, I needed to wrap the element in a g element. The final product look like:

```
<g id="shape3" v:mID="3" v:groupContext="shape">
    <v:custProps>
        <v:cp v:nameU="Row_1" v:lbl="data1" v:type="0" v:langID="1033" v:val="VT4(data value 1)" />
        <v:cp v:nameU="Row_2" v:lbl="data2" v:type="0" v:langID="1033" v:val="VT4(data value 2)" />
    </v:custProps>
    <rect x="595" y="40" fill="white" width="45" height="33"  />
</g>
```